# VBA filtering based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have an Excel workbook where a user inputs up to four keywords from a drop-down list in cells C4:C7 of sheet "Report generator", and my VBA code then takes these keywords, does a filtering on another sheet called "Data", copies the filtered rows and pastes them in a Word file as a report. The code works for up to two keywords at the same time, but for some reason fails when having three or four and I cannot understand why. Specifically, when having three or four keywords the filtering returns 0 rows so there is nothing to copy. This is not an issue if I try to do it manually in Excel so it's not a problem of the data.

Below is the part of the code that does the filtering. As you can see, the if loop checks sequentially whether each keyword is blank starting from the last one, and applies the filled-in keywords to the filtering. The loop finishes successfully every time, but for some reason the filtering command in cases of 3 or 4 keywords returns 0 rows. Could you please help me to understand why this happens? Thank you!

```
    'Filter data based on keywords selected
Sheets("Data").Select

'If user inputs 1 keyword
If IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C7")) = True And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C6")) = True And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C5")) = True Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Array("*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C4").Value & "*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

'If user inputs 2 keywords
ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C7")) = True And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C6")) = True Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Array("*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C4").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C5").Value & "*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

'If user inputs 3 keywords
ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C7")) = True Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Array("*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C4").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C5").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C6").Value & "*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

'If user inputs 4 keywords
ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C7")) = False And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C6")) = False And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C5")) = False And IsEmpty(Sheets("Report generator").Range("C4")) = False Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Array("*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C4").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C5").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C6").Value & "*", _
        "*" & Sheets("Report generator").Range("C7").Value & "*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If
```

Comment: You don't need the = True after the IsEmpty() functions.

Comment: You cannot have more than **2 elements with wild characters** in the `Criteria1` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Data

- The main issue is that you cannot use more than two elements **containing wild characters** in the `Criteria1` array.
- The following will copy the filtered data to a third worksheet (`Report`). You could then export it to `Word`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilteredData()
    
    Const lName As String = "Report Generator"
    Const lrgAddress As String = "C4:C7"
    
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const sCols As String = "A:F"
    Const sfField As Long = 5
    
    Const dName As String = "Report"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Const doCopyHeaders As Boolean = True ' e.g. if dFirst = "A2" then 'False'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the criterias to a dictionary.
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(lrgAddress)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim lString As String
    
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        lString = CStr(lCell.Value)
        If Len(lString) > 0 Then
            dict("*" & lString & "*") = Empty
        End If
    Next lCell
    
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = dict.Count
    If dCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no criterias
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Source Table Range
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(sCols)
    ' Source Data Range ('strg' without headers)
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    Select Case dCount
    
    Case Is < 3 ' up to two criteria with wild characters
        
        strg.AutoFilter sfField, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
        Set srg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    Case Else ' more criteria with wild characters
        
        Dim fpCount As Long: fpCount = Int(dCount / 2)
        Dim UB As Long: UB = 1
        Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(0 To 1)
        
        Dim sfdrg As Range
        Dim fp As Long
        Dim n As Long
        
        ' For each filter pair...
        For fp = 0 To fpCount
            If fp = fpCount Then ' last loop only
                If dCount Mod 2 = 1 Then ' count is odd: needs to loop once more
                    UB = 0
                    ReDim arr(0 To 0)
                Else ' count is even: no need to loop anymore
                    UB = -1
                End If
            End If
            If UB > -1 Then
                ' Write criteria pair to an array.
                For n = 0 To UB
                    arr(n) = dict.Keys()(n + fp * 2)
                Next n
                ' Filter Source Data Range.
                sdrg.AutoFilter sfField, arr, xlFilterValues
                ' Combine filtered range into Source Range.
                On Error Resume Next
                Set sfdrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
                sws.AutoFilterMode = False
                If Not sfdrg Is Nothing Then
                    If srg Is Nothing Then
                        Set srg = sfdrg
                    Else
                        Set srg = Union(srg, sfdrg)
                    End If
                    Set sfdrg = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next fp
        
    End Select
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If doCopyHeaders Then
        Set srg = Union(strg.Rows(1), srg)
    End If
    Debug.Print srg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Copy to the Destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    dws.Cells.Clear
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
End Sub
```